# Excel のセル内の改行文字を Python のコードで削除したい

Tags: python, python3, openpyxl

Pythons初心者ですので、質問が不作法の場合ご容赦くださいませ。

### 環境

- Windows 11
- Pyhton 3.11.2
- openpyxl 3.1.2

### 質問

1. Pythonのコードで、エクセルで（ALT＋ENTER）で改行されているセルの値を改行なしに変換。
2. 1.と同様にセル内に全角と半角のスペースを削除。
3. セル内の値は左詰め。

問題点の指摘とコードの改善をご指導いただけますと幸甚です。

コードは以下の通りです。

```
import openpyxl
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb.active

for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value and isinstance(cell.value, str): 
            print(repr(cell.value))
            cell.value = cell.value.replace('\n', '').replace('　', '').replace(' ', '')
            cell.alignment = openpyxl.styles.Alignment(horizontal='left')            

new_filename = filename.replace('.xlsx', '-改行解除.xlsx')
wb.save(new_filename)
```

Comment: 「問題点の指摘」とのことですが、現在のコードは質問者さんのやりたいことが実現できているのでしょうか？

Comment: merinoさんコメントや私の回答に付いているコメントのように、どういう状況なのかもう少し詳細を追記してみてください。問題が有るのか無いのか、問題が有ればその状況・内容や考えられる原因/正しく動作するとしたらどういう結果か等、問題無いなら他に何を求めているのかの詳細(例えば削除する文字(文字列)を外から指定したい/現在の処理が稚拙に見えるので賢く見える(まとめたり正規表現を使った)処理にしたい/処理は出来るが遅いので速くしたい(速度なら量とか種別とかの条件や実測値も沿えて)等)な説明をお願いします。

Comment: 皆様のコメント・ご協力に感謝申し上げます。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @xuegan さん、お礼よりも上にコメントしたように何が問題/要望だったのか等の詳細を追記してもらった方が良いですね。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

質問の仕方が悪かったのか、Chat-GPT4の調子が悪かったのかは判りませんが、
先ほど以下コードで解決いたしましたので、取り急ぎご報告いたします。

```
import os
import re
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename

def remove_newlines_and_spaces(cell_value):
    cell_value = re.sub(r'\n', '', cell_value)
    cell_value = re.sub(r'　', '', cell_value)
    cell_value = re.sub(r' ', '', cell_value)
    return cell_value

Tk().withdraw()
file_path = askopenfilename(title="エクセルファイルを選択してください", filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.xlsx")])

if file_path:
    wb = load_workbook(file_path)
    ws = wb.active

    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value and isinstance(cell.value, str):
                cell.value = remove_newlines_and_spaces(cell.value)

    save_path = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".xlsx", initialfile=os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_path))[0] + "-改行解除済", title="保存先を選択してください", filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.xlsx")])

    if save_path:
        wb.save(save_path)
        print("処理が完了しました。")
else:
    print("ファイルが選択されませんでした。")
```

Answer (score 0):

「（ALT＋ENTER）で改行されているセル」と同等の内容と思われるCSVファイルからExcelで変換して作成した.xlsxファイルに対して質問のスクリプトを実行すると、スクリプト中の`print(repr(cell.value))`の表示では`_x000D_`(もしくは`_x000D_\n`?)という文字列が入っています。

それで検索すると以下のような記事が見つかります。
[エクセルファイルに _x000D_ という文字列が挿入されるトラブルと解決法](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/11892517.html)
[ディクレ サポートBBS - [TCARD for CE]](http://www.dicre.com/bbs/thread.php?tid=110) の`11　2013/04/03 16:19:40`の欄
[Access newline becoming _x000D_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36167807/9014308)
[DURING EXCEL DATA IMPORT - LINE FEEDS CONVERTED TO _X000D_](https://community.dynamics.com/365/sales/f/dynamics-365-for-sales-forum/417694/during-excel-data-import---line-feeds-converted-to-_x000d_)

ちなみに最新版にアップデートしているMicrosoft 365 のExcelの操作として「（ALT＋ENTER）で改行」した際にはそれは入っていませんでしたし、質問のスクリプトで問題無く削除出来ていました。

ということで質問のスクリプトで処理できなかったのだとしたら、おそらくセル内の改行は`_x000D_`または`_x000D_\n`だと思われます。
(上記紹介記事の2番目によると`_x001F_`もそうらしいですが)

なので、こちらの行にもう一つ置換処理を足して：

```
cell.value = cell.value.replace('\n', '').replace('　', '').replace(' ', '')
```

このようにしてみてはどうでしょう？(なお必要ならば`_x001F_`も追加)

```
cell.value = cell.value.replace('_x000D_', '').replace('\n', '').replace('　', '').replace(' ', '')
```

Comment: 不正な入力対応はその意図を持って作られたソフトでその対象だけに限定すべきです。そうでないと、思わぬ副作用が起こるケースがあります。例えば、今の回答をExcel保存してスクリプトにかけたら多分消えちゃって意味が分からなくなりますよね。Excelによる編集だけで意図せず入ってしまうのであれば検討が必要かと思いますが(もしそういう話であれば、作り方も明記してください)、そうでなければ必要ないかと思います。

Comment: @dameo さん、質問記事には書かれていない情報を基に回答の方にコメントされても困りますね。そういうコメントは質問の方にするべきでは？

Comment: 変なことを言ってますね。「エクセルで（ALT＋ENTER）で改行されているセルの値を改行なしに変換」と書かれていますよ？本当にこの操作で0x0dや0x1fが入るのですか？入るのであれば、入れ方を明記してください。入らないのであれば、不正な入力対応は、要件外のことを勝手にしていると言っているに過ぎません。副作用があるのは特にまずいです。質問に不備があれば質問にコメントしますよ。

Comment: @dameo さん、「不正な入力対応」というのは貴方が質問記事から推測したであろう内容であって、実際には書かれていませんよね。私の方はスクリプトを動作させて質問に書かれた「1.」の項目の動作が出来ていなかった(変更されたExcelファイルではセル内改行が削除されていなかった)ので、それが問題であろうと判断(質問のタイトルにもありますし)して、スクリプトを変更したらどうでしょうと回答したものです。

Comment: さん、ではどうやったら_x000D_が入るのでしょうか？私の環境では入りませんよ。

Comment: @dameo さん、だからそれは質問に対するコメントでしょうから回答にコメントしても意味が無いと言っているのですが。

Comment: さん、「エクセルで（ALT＋ENTER）で改行」では_x000D_は入らないのではないか？と言っています。これが入る可能性があるから対応せよと言ってるのはあなたです。あなた以外にコメントする人はいません。

Comment: @dameo さん、回答に書いた紹介記事の内容と、改行を含む文字列がセルに入ったCSVファイルをExcelに変換したものを対象に処理した実績で判断しています。質問者さんの状況で実際にどうなるかは、私の回答を見た質問者さんの結果が出れば分かるでしょう。質問者さんの状況を外野が忖度しても意味は無いと思われます。

Comment: 「エクセルで（ALT＋ENTER）で改行」で_x000D_は入るのでしょうか？入らないのですか？どっちかハッキリしてください。

Comment: @dameo さん、まあそこに拘っているならたしかにExcel上の操作でやったわけでは無いので違いますね。ただそれが入っていないなら質問のスクリプトで問題無く変換出来るので質問自体が行われないのでは？と思われます。回答の方は正確な記述に変更しておきましょう。

Comment: 副作用があることも明記してくださいね。意図して_x000Dを記述した場合も変換してしまうことも付記してください。あと、毎回valueを書き換えるよりは、正規表現でマッチング処理してから必要な場合のみの方がいいです。

Comment: @dameo さん、別に貴方がより正確だと思う回答や補足を独自に行うことを誰も妨げてはいないので、そのへんは勝手にやってください。私も時々既に付いた回答に補足の回答を付けたりしています。

Comment: 明らかに間違っていたので、コメントしたに過ぎません。正規表現については、ついで書いてくれ程度の要望です。質問者さんは「改善」をご所望なので。

Answer (score 0):

既に解決済みですが、`remove_newlines_and_spaces()` 関数は不要で、二重ループの部分を以下の様に書き換えてもよいかと思います。

```py
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value and isinstance(cell.value, str):
            cell.value = re.sub(r'[\n　 ]', '', cell_value)
```